# Multiple assertions in a Ruby Test::Unit test class skipped on first failure

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I've looked at several related questions and their answers, but none seem to quite address my issue.

My unit tests are typically data-driven by an external dataset, for ease of extension and maintenance.  I test my primitives with all sorts of inputs.  As an example, I have a `#truthify` method that evaluates its argument according to specific rules (**not** Ruby's usual ones).  The set of test inputs keeps expanding.

So I have two test classes, one for testing that 'true' arguments are evaluated correctly, and one for 'false' arguments.  Each class iterates through its set of inputs and makes an assertion in the loop.  The first one that fails, however, aborts that test class' processing.

That is one of my more simple examples.

The last time I used `Test::Unit` (years ago), ISTR there was a way to have each failed assertion reported without aborting the test class.

Writing a separate test class for each test value, even if I simplify things with subclassing, is far too unwieldy and unmaintainable, and I feel it also violates KISS and DRY.

If there's no way to tell `Test::Unit` to continue after a failed assertion, is there a way to dynamically alter the list of test classes in the test case?  That way I could at least have the case initialisation dynamically add all those individual test classes based on the values in the external dataset.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, one way that I could imagine (though I use `rspec`, instead) is to wrap testing in blocks, so you could assert that no exception is being raised.

Comment: The thing is, `Test::Unit` registers an assertion failure by raising an exception.  Some systems' exception handling protocols permit for the handler to say, "Okey, I've dealt with the exception, continue from where it was raised."  I don't think Linux has that, and even the soft exceptions in Ruby don't.  AFAIK.  If Ruby did, it would be brilliant if `Test::Unit` had a configuration option to enable it — then `Test::Unit` could handle its own 'assertion failed' exception and allow the testing to continue.  But no. :-(

Comment: Can you provide any kind of simplified example? It seems like you could theoretically use a small amount of meta-programming such that each test case would run in it's own test (own method) or even generate N number of test classes with very minimal additional effort. Given that you are already running the code in a loop such an alteration seems like it would be relatively straight forward; however, at the moment it is difficult to say so definitively based solely on the explanation provided and without any code to go on.

Comment: You might need to look at how Test::Unit::TestCase is using Test::Unit::ErrorHandler, Test::Unit::ExceptionHandler, and Test::Unit::FailureHandler so you can avoid exiting on errors or exceptions. RSpec or MiniTest have more options for either "failing fast" or exception handling in ways that could allow a set of tests to continue.

Comment: @RoUS I don't recommend it, but you can register a handler using [Test::Unit::ExceptionHandler::ClassMethods#exception_handler](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/test-unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/ExceptionHandler/ClassMethods.html#method-i-exception_handlers) that returns a truthy value, but it's up to you to make sure that the exception is handled (and possibly registered with the correct observer) properly. It's definitely not as flexible as RSpec or MiniTest, but should be possible. You could potentially rescue an exception within the test itself, too, but it *can* get tricky.

Comment: A failed assertion raises [AssertionFailedError](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/test-unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/AssertionFailedError.html). If you don't want to register a handler, you could potentially rescue the exception, report it, and then continue. Otherwise, maybe you can put your data validation into a separate test suite so you aren't mixing up cleansing/validation of your test data with application behavior. Thinking about whether you *should* continue testing with invalid data is something you should consider anyway.

Comment: I'm concerned that attempting to intercept [AssertionFailedError](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/test-unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/AssertionFailedError.html) in any way would break `Test::Unit`'s processing.  I view unit testing as being inclusive: "Does this unit/function operate correctly in all cases?"  Which includes "Does it handle invalid input correctly?" as well as "Does it do the right thing with valid input?"  Perhaps that's an anti-pattern, but it's how I work.

Comment: @engineersmnky Meta-programming for the win, although it looks rather ugly.  It's definitely better than writing hundreds of individual test methods!  And the fact that `#send` doesn't care about symbol syntax means the defined methods can have meaningfule names, like `test_truthiness_of_Complex_(1.0-0.1i)`, which further eases the automation.  If you want to post your idea as an answer I can accept it, or I'll answer my own question with details about How I Did It and give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: @RoUS please feel free to answer your own question as I still have no actual details to go on.

Answer (score 1):

> a way to have each failed assertion reported without aborting the test class

Each assertion would have to be in its own test method:

```rb
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  10.times do |i|
    define_method "test_#{i}" do
      assert false, "Assertion was false."
    end
  end
end
```

```
10 tests, 10 assertions, 10 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed
```

---

> a way to dynamically alter the list of test classes in the test case

You can selectively require files as needed:

```rb
# test/run.rb

require "test/unit"

# require whatever tests you want to run
require_relative "./my_test"

Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run
```

or regex test classes from command line:

```
$ ruby test/run.rb --testcase=/myte/i
```

Comment: The first part might approach what I'm hoping to do.  Let me experiment with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Meta-programming as suggested by @alex and @engineersmnky solved my issue.  As in my earlier comment: @engineersmnky Meta-programming for the win, although it looks rather ugly. It's definitely better than writing hundreds of individual test methods! And the fact that `#send` doesn't care about symbol syntax means the defined methods can have meaningful names, like `test_truthiness_of_Complex_(1.0-0.1i)`, which further eases the automation.  Thanks!